# Auto increment value left behind / lower than actual values

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

Is it possible that at some point, a table has had IDs higher than the current AUTO_INCREMENT value?

I have a table that acts like a queue. I insert/delete 10-30 rows per second and need the auto increment column to keep going. When I insert rows now, I get a recycled auto increment (id), eg: `374097`.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `id` INT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=374098;
```

There's another table that uses this `id` as a foreign key.

```
SELECT max(batch_id) from secondary_table;
```

Returns: `397959`. **At some point, test_table has had IDs up to `397959`, while the AUTO_INCREMENT is way lower!**

I read about this on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html and I should be safe - the AUTO_INCREMENT is set on a simple primary key.

Any idea if I can keep using AUTO_INCREMENT like this, or do I need to use a self-provided ID?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: You should read this https://serverfault.com/questions/228690/mysql-auto-increment-fields-resets-by-itself and refer to the manual for your version of mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon: you're right, I left that out. It's actually AWS Aurora, which I had the impression was up-to-date MySQL with some tweaks, but is actually "compatible with MySQL 5.7".

Answer (score 1):

you can keep auto increment : you just have to update your auto increment value on your first table to your max value + 1

```
ALTER TABLE test_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 397959 + 1
```

Comment: I know how to fix it, the issue is broader than that, I need to know if what I'm doing is OK or I risk running into the same issue later.

Comment: using auto increment is safe, even if this id is use in another table as foreign key. the matter is how you do to get an higher foreign_id in the second table than the original auto increment.

Comment: The problem is the other way around. The foreign_id was correct until the auto_increment was rolled back a bit, because probably the IDs were no longer in the table when mysql restarted.

Comment: it must other thing : yes of course, auto increment is an integrated part in table : ACID principe (since MySQL 8.0). you can see it with : SELECT TABLE_NAME,AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES